# piping python variable value to bash script (inside python script)

Tags: scripting, python

After years of bash scripting I've been given the task of modifying a python script to have it call a shell script when certain conditions are met.  That part wasn't too bad, but now I'm trying to also send this shell script a variable from within the python script and I'm getting lost.

The shell script takes stdin, which is where I'm trying to place the value of the python variable, which is just an interger.

my code (so far) looks like this:

```
if VAR > NUMBER:
import os
bashCommand = "echo something | /path/to/script --args"
os.system(bashCommand)
```

and it works just fine.  But what I am looking to do is make os.system(bashCommand) an equivalent of:

```
echo $VAR | /path/to/script --args
```

or even

```
echo 'some text' $VAR | /path/to/script --args
```

given the way os.system appears to work though it seems I'm approaching this completely wrong.

So I guess my question is how can I pass the value of VAR to bashCommand, preferably as stdin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't expand variables in strings in the same way as bash.  If you have `VAR` in python and want to pass that to bash you could do

```
subprocess.call('echo {} | /path/to/script --args'.format(VAR), shell=True)
```

if `VAR` in python holds the name of a bash variable you want to expand you could do similar:

```
subprocess.call('echo "${}" | /path/to/script --args'.format(VAR), shell=True)
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the best-practice/security issues of using "shell=' but this worked for me.  Marking resolved.

Comment: This is a bad practice. If you use shell=true, you should escape VAR with shlex.. so it will be :   .... .format(shlex.quote(VAR))

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `os.system()`, it is deprecated in favor of `subprocess` module.

In your case you can use `subprocess` module directly and its better to not use the `shell=True` parameter as this is not safe to run commands directly into the shell. All the functionalities you need here like pipe can be emulated by the `subprocess` module.

Lets take this example :

```
import subprocess
var = 'foobar'

first = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/echo', var], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
second = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '/path/to/script', '--args'], stdin=first.stdout)
```

we have defined a varible `var`, then we have used the `subprocess.Popen` class to get the value of `var` using `/bin/echo` and then sent this value to the pipe. The `first` is an object of `subprocess.Popen` class.

Then we have used the STDOUT of `first` as STDIN of `second` via pipe and executed the `bash` script accordingly.

If you want to save the output of a command as a string use `subprocess.check_output` function instead e.g. :

```
second = subprocess.check_output(['bash', '/path/to/script', '--args'], stdin=first.stdout)
```

Read the [offical documentation of subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to get more idea.

Comment: This is great information and I think I could use it.  The one thing I think I should mention though is that 'VAR' is a variable (integer) defined by the python script (that is to call the shell script) so we may not need to echo it, right?  since python already knows its value.

Comment: @kadamwolfe Yeah..you can use it directly then as I have used in the `second` object generation..I was just pointing out the processes in my sample script..fit it to meet your need :)

Comment: nice.  so something like....  subprocess.Popen(['bash', '/path/to/script', '--args'], stdin="some text" VAR) ?

Comment: @kadamwolfe I probably have misunderstood your point, you can't directly use a string as STDIN as it does not have `fileno` attribute..you can combine the two into a simple one liner: `subprocess.Popen(['bash', '/path/to/script'], stdin=subprocess.Popen(['/bin/echo', var], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout)` ,if its a one time run then you can consider `subprocess.call` instead of `subprocess.Popen`..

Comment: While I do appreciate the help, I'm not sure it resolves my issue.  I'm checking if a variable's value is greater than another and if so, echo that variable's value to a shell script (preferably pre-pended by a text string.   `if VAR > NUMBER: ` `<echo text string + VAR's value to /path/to/script --args>`

Comment: @kadamwolfe All the ingredients are in there, if it is not solving your problem you need to be specific about where it is failing so that we can take a look at the exact point..

Answer (score 0):

Calling `os.system()` is deprecated, though still valid. That functionality may be going away in the future (probably will be), so you might want to give serious consideration to refactoring those calls with the `subprocess` module, which has an very easy way to send data to a subprocess's STDIN and read from its STDOUT. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the good practice is:

```
var = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/echo', var], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
second = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '/path/to/script', '--args'],stdin=var.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
var.stdout.close()
output = second.communicate()[0]
var.wait()
```